# Zoom hides last point from series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I just found this strange behavior, I don´t know if it's a misused property or if it's some kind of bug.

If I zoom for a 6 months periods it seems to work, but if I scroll to the beginning of the series the last value of the column series is hidden. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/7agLjhk6/) is a working example.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
  },
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Zoom broken on 6m'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: [{},{}],

  series: timeSeriesParser.map(set=> ({
        ...set,

      })),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because the column needs additional space to be rendered. Another problem is that notice that for some particular data 6months means something different - for example in the case which you described the 6 months range starts on `March 1, 2011`, but ends on the `Aug 31, 2011` - meanwhile the next column point starts on the `Sep 1, 2011`.

I have two ideas on how to solve this issue:

- Set the pointPlacement to 'on':

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lze67jf3/

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPlacement: 'on',
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.pointPlacement

- Or set the `getExtremesFromAll` to true:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/78wte2hs/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.getExtremesFromAll